# Understanding Debug Memory Graph

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks

I'm using Debug Memory Graph to locate some memory leaks.

I fixed everything i found in my code but i still get some memory leaks in

> libsswiftcore
>
> CoreFoundation
>
> libswiftFoundation

Am i missing something? are these leaks in my code?

[image: Debug Memory Graph snapshot]

Thanks

---

The leaks where in my code and found them using Leaks instrument.

I still have 1 leak in the Debug Memory Graph but no leaks in Leaks instrument.

Comment: A couple of questions: 1. Is this the full list of leaks? I don't see any of your app's objects listed here and don't know if that's artful screen capture, or whether you're saying that you're 100% positive that none of your objects have leaked. I ask because when you leak a high level object, it can lead to a cascade of system level objects that were leaked, but it's an exercise in futility to analyze those mallocs and the like if you haven't first fixed top level leaks. I know you said you found everything in your code, but just double checking. ;)

Comment: 2. I'd suggest temporarily using "malloc scribble" option because you can sometimes get false positives from "debug memory graph". 3. I'd suggest temporarily using "malloc stack" option so that you can see the stack trace, so you can track these strong references to locations in your own code. Don't worry about stack traces where your code doesn't appear; but focus on stack traces where your app appears. 4. I've found that "Debug memory graph" is not 100% accurate. Have you also run it through Instruments and confirmed what's leaking there via "Allocations" tool?

Comment: 1. this is the full leak list from one ViewController.
I fixed my objects leaks and these are left.
2. what does "malloc scribble" do? and where can i fins this option?

Comment: Thanks i found the leak using Leaks instrument (it was in my code).
i have one leak left, i updated my question, thanks again

Comment: "Malloc scribble" is one of the debugging options when you edit your project's scheme.