# Using instruments tool to locate leaks

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, instruments, xcode-instruments

I am trying to find leaks in my app using the leaks instrument.
When the app launches I can see 106 leaks and I am having trouble in finding them.

[image]

In the image you can see part of the list, but how can I drill down to the  class or line of code that generates the leak?

Comment: Before any advanced one , use debug memory graph to find those purple `!` and solve them

Comment: @E.Coms can you elaborate?

Comment: search `debug memory graph` in SO. like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803692/understanding-debug-memory-graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding a leak is not that simple. You need to wear the detective cap, take out your magnifying glass from your coat and start find the trail. i.e.

For every leaked object there is a responsible library. If it is a UIKit, Foundation or anything low-level, you won't be able to pin point the location of code that is causing the leak since these libraries are in the form of binaries.

If the responsible library is the one you are writing then you can go to the code by clicking the right method in the stack trace panel on the right. One hint is that the methods listed in the stack trace panel become highlighted if there is a corresponding code available.

But, since it is not that straight forward, often your own piece of code causes some internal library to leak which is hard to debug. You need to go through some tutorials and practice material before you start. Something certainly not answerable on stackoverflow.

Comment: The problem is that i cant get to my code through the stack trace panel,
is there something wrong that i am doing?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the stack trice in right side of the screen. And after that to scroll to the class and method that create the leak. Sometimes is hard to understand why you have the leak.

Take look on my image [image]

I have TermsViewController and I have NSMuttableAttributed string which creates memory leaks. Also if I select the row with TermsViewController.setupInfoText() it opens the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the code allocating the leaked memory, switch to the call tree view using the jump bar. To find your code in the call tree view, invert the call tree view and hide the system libraries.

[image]

Double-clicking one of your functions in the call tree view will let you drill down to the line of code that allocated the leaked memory.

Read the following article for more detailed information on using Instruments to find memory leaks:

[Measuring Your App's Memory Usage with Instruments](https://swiftdevjournal.com/measuring-your-apps-memory-usage-with-instruments/)

Comment: Ok, so i did that and i got some of the pieces of the puzzle.
I can see that most of the leaks are from cocoapods like: alamofire,swinjectstoryboard and so.
is that make sense ?
in addition i still can access some actual code

Comment: It's possible that external frameworks in CocoaPods have memory leaks. I haven't used Instruments with CocoaPods so I can't tell you if there's any way to determine what leaks are in your code and what leaks are in the CocoaPods.